# IndexError: list index out of range using MapReduce

Tags: python

I'm brand new to Python and getting the following error when trying to use MapReduce patterns to find the top 10 values in a dataset. Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
    name           market_value
1   Alexis Sanchez     65
2   Mesut Ozil         50
3   Petr Cech           7
4   Theo Walcott       20
5   Laurent Koscielny  22
6   Hector Bellerin    30
7   Olivier Giroud     22
8   Nacho Monreal      13
9   Shkodran Mustafi   30
10  Alex Iwobi         10
```

The Python script that is run, `Mapper.py`, is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

myList = []
n = 10  # Number of top N records

for line in sys.stdin:

    line = line.strip()
    data = line.split("\t")


    try:
        market_value = int(data[2])
    except ValueError:
        continue

    myList.append( (market_value, line) )
    myList.sort(reverse=True)

    if len(myList) > n:
        myList = myList[:n]

# Print top N records
for (k,v) in myList:
    print(v)
```

When this code is run, I'm getting the following error:

```
market_value = int(data[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Im not sure what the error is here because the `market_value` column is the 2nd field, so I can't see how it is outputting this error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have used  `except ValueError` But `int(data[2])` is throwing `IndexError`. Change `ValueError` to `IndexError`

Comment: You are splitting on a tab - `'\t'` - but there might be just spaces there. I would suggest simply adding a `print(data)` after the line where you define `data` and just see why you get the error. Basic debugging

Comment: BTW, just to be clear, `data[2]` is the **third** element of the list as indices start from `0`

Answer (score 0):

Generally it means that you are providing an index for which a list element does not exist. 
E.g, if your list was [1, 3, 5, 7] , and you asked for the element at index 10, you would be well out of bounds and receive an error, as only elements 0 through 3 exist.